What are the covering spaces of $\mathbb{Q}$?
Let $X = \mathbb{Q}$, topologized as a subset of the real line.  Is there a reasonable description of the covering spaces of $X$?
Here is something more precise.  One way of constructing covers $p: \widetilde{X} \rightarrow X$ is as follows.  Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a closed set of irrational numbers.  The complement $\mathbb{R} \setminus C$ contains $X$ and can be written as a disjoint union of open intervals.  Let these intervals be $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$, and for each $i \in I$ let $J_i$ be a discrete set.  Let $J$ be the disjoint union of all the $J_i$, and let
$$\widetilde{X} = \{(x,j) \mid \text{there exists $i \in I$ with $x \in U_i \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $j \in J_i$}\} \subset \mathbb{R} \times J.$$
Topologize $\widetilde{X}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R} \times J$, and let $p\colon \widetilde{X} \rightarrow X$ be the natural projection.
Question: does this construction give all the covers of $X$, or are there more?

Yes.
For a cardinal $c$ let $V_c\subset X$ be the set of all $x$ such that $c$ is the cardinality of $p^{-1}(x)$. So $X$ is the union of some set of disjoint nonempty open sets $V_c$ such that when restricted to $V_c$ the covering space becomes one whose fibers are of constant cardinality. I will show that in this case the covering space becomes trivial when restricted to $V_c$.
So the statement to be proved is that when $V$ is a nonempty open subset of $X$ then any covering space of $V$ whose fibers are of constant cardinality must be trivial. Choose $W$ open in $\mathbb R$ such that $W\cap X=V$. The set $W$ is the disjoint union of connected open sets $W'$, and $V$ is the disjoint union of open sets $V'=W'\cap V$. If the covering space of $V$ is trivial over each of these sets $V'$, then it is trivial. Thus we may assume without loss of generality that $W$ is connected, i.e. a finite or infinite open interval.
Lemma: Let $W$ be an open interval and consider a covering space of $W\cap X$ whose fibers have constant cardinality. If $I$ and $J$ are open intervals in $W$ such that the covering space is trivial on $I\cap X$ and trivial on $J\cap X$, then it is also trivial on $(I\cup J)\cap X$.
Proof: If $I\cap J$ is empty, or if $I\subset J$ or $J\subset I$, then this is certainly true. If not, then choose an irrational point $b$ in the interval $I\cap J$. It cuts $(I\cup J)\cap X$ into two open sets, one contained in $I\cap X$ and the other contained in $J\cap X$, and we have trivializations over both of these. QED
Now exhaust $W$ by increasing compact intervals $K_1\subset K_2\subset \dots$.
By covering $K_j$ with finitely many open intervals $I$ such that the covering space is trivial on $I\cap X$, and then using the lemma repeatedly, we find that the covering space is trivial on $I_j\cap X$ for some open interval $I_j$ containing $K_j$.
Using the lemma, or its proof, again, we find that we can in fact arrange for the trivialization on a neighborhood of $K_{j+1}$ to extend one previously chosen on a neighborhood of $K_j$.

Very nice!  So all covers come from the construction in my post, but many of them are non-obviously isomorphic.  In particular, for any cardinality $c$ the only $c$-fold cover of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the trivial one.

Yes. The isomorphism class of a cover is determined by the locally constant function that gives the cardinalities of the fibers.
